# What is difference between global methods and instance methods in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Vue.js official docs about [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html) describes global methods and properties and Vue instance methods.

```
// 1. add global method or property
Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {
  // some logic ...
}

// 4. add an instance method
Vue.prototype.$myMethod = function (methodOptions) {
  // some logic ...
}
```

But it isn't clear which of this approach is better fit to define global functionality? Can someone explain difference or indicate some resource about different use cases of this two approaches?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An instance method will have an instance (`this`) to be called from an operate on. A global-on-Vue function would have `Vue` itself as its `this`, which probably means you wouldn't want to use `this` in it.

So: instance method if it should operate on an instance, global function if it is some sort of utility that doesn't operate on a Vue instance.